# mysqli connection not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I have a connection class which should connect to the database for me but it is not working.

connection.php -

```
<?php

    require_once "config.php";

    class connection{

        public static $db_con;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db_con = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $password, $database_name);

            if($this->db_con->connect_error){
                echo "Connection falied for " . $this->db_con->connect_errno . "\n";
                return $this->db_con->connect_errno;
            }
            else{
                echo "Connection Successful";
                return $this->db_con;
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

my config.php looks like -

```
<?php
    define("server_name", "localhost:8889");
    define("database_name", "myStore");
    define("user_name", "root");
    define("password", "root");
?>
```

In my index page,  am trying to establish the database connection by doing

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";

    $db = new connection();

?>
```

I should either see the success msg or the error msg, but I am getting nothing. Total blank page. Can anyone please help.

I am updating the files according to  u_mulder's suggestion which solved one problem but now there is another.

Now I am eating the following error-

Notice : Undefined variable: server_name in connection.php on line 10
         Undefined variable: user_name in connection.php on line 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class constructor defined via `__construct` function.

In older php versions constructor can also be named as a class name, that is `connection`

Currently you function `__connection` is just a function, and not a constructor. Either rename it to act like a constructor or call it explicitly:

```
$db = new connection();
$db->__connection();
```

Also, variables `$server_name, $user_name, $password, $database_name` will not be available in scope of `connection` class. You should either pass them as arguments to a function, or declare values as constants.

**Update:**

If you define some values as constants, as you said:

```
define("server_name", "localhost:8080");
```

Then `server_name` is a constant name and should be used **without** `$` sign:

```
$this->db_con = new mysqli(server_name, user_name, password, database_name);
```

For not mixing constants with variables it's recommended to name constants in `UPPER_CASE`, like:

```
define("SERVER_NAME", "localhost:8080");
```

Comment: I changed the config.php file to <?php

 define("server_name", "localhost:8080");
 define("database_name", "myStore");
 define("user_name", "root");
 define("password", "");
?> but still I get Undefined variable error

Comment: When I run index.php. I just changed the config.php file as I stated above and changed the __connection to __construct in connection.php file.

Comment: What variable is undefined?

Comment: all the variables that were declared as constants(as you suggested) in the config.php file like server_name, database_name, user_name, password.

Answer (score 0):

Change __connection to __construct